# Chaining a Reduce-only job in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am implementing a chain of MR-jobs in Hadoop 2.2.0 using ControlledJobs. The basic schema is this:

```
mapper1 -> reducer1 -> mapper2 -> reducer2
```

But, mapper2 is the identity. Is there a way to easily let reducer1 generate key-value-pairs and pass them to reducer2?

Right now, the job output for both rounds is configured as follows:

```
// set intermediate/mapper output
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

// set reducer output
job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Comment: If you did nt give mapper2 also , an identity mapper will be executed by default

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, identity mapper is still a mapper and you can't bypass it. However, I believe in some cases you can refactor mapper1, reducer1 and reducer2 into one single job so that it will become: mapper1 -> reducer1. That totally depends on your use case and what data you trying to reduce (twice) here.

Comment: I do not think this is possible in our case, as the keys are of a different kind for both reducers, causing a radically different grouping.

Comment: Would you mind to share your data flow and types, maybe simplified variant in case if you do not want to disclose any proprietary info. That would help me to check if collapsing into one job is possible.

Comment: A simplified setting (I cannot give more details, sorry): consider 2 files, a file A that contains name,number-pairs, and a file B that contains numbers. We now count per name the amount of numbers that appear in file B. First, both types are converted to (number,content) key-value pairs. Then only matching number are kept. Then, they are projected to (name, number) key-value pairs and the amount of distinct numbers is calculated.

Comment: So in first job you do kind of inner join by number... How big are the files A and B? Will data either from A or from B fit into memory?

Comment: both will not fit in memory.

Comment: Ok, what about sort order of A and B? Does it match? Can you possibly do join on a mapper side?

Comment: you mean whether they are sorted on the number field?

Comment: Yep. If they are sorted then you could use map side join